# Can't route some files in php

Tags: php

I'm following Laravel Cast tuotrial on php and I'm stuck on a thing
When trying to route some files, I got the error

> "Fatal error: Uncaught Exception: No route defined for this URI. in C:\xampp\htdocs\Php-Learning\core\Router.php:27 Stack trace:
>
> #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\Php-Learning\index.php(6): Router->direct('Php-Learning/in...')
>
> #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\Php-Learning\core\Router.php on line 27"

I'm stuck on this for few days and I try to find some solution but no one work>
I use all .htaccess solutions I find but it never solve the problem.
Here is thhe common solution to the problem but I never work for me

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^.*$ /index.php [L,QSA]
```

Could any one help please
Thanks for those who will help.

I don't really understand what file I have to post so I let these two here
Here is how I generate

```
    <?php

$router->define([
    '' => 'controllers/index.php',
    'about' => 'controllers/about.php',
    'about/culture' => 'controllers/about-culture.php',
    'contact' => 'controllers/contact.php'
]);
```

And here is the router file

```
  <?php

class Router
{
    protected $routes = [];

    public static function load($file)
    {
        $router = new static;

        require $file;

        return $router;
    }

    public function define($routes)
    {
        $this->routes = $routes;
    }

    public function direct($uri)
    {
        if (array_key_exists($uri, $this->routes)) {
            return $this->routes[$uri];
        }

        throw new Exception('No route defined for this URI.');
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: You might want to look at your routes file instead of your htaccess.

Comment: And how can I do that please I'm not an expert.

Comment: Post your routes file (or whatever is relevant) along with how you're trying to generate the route.

Comment: Ok see my post under

Comment: You should [edit] your post instead of adding as an answer. Are you using actual Laravel, or just following a laracast video? And what is the route that you're trying to go to?

Comment: I'm following a Laracast video. I don't understand the second question please